# In Minimax, how should we handle draws?

Tags: game-theory

A player playing the [Minimax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) strategy should choose moves which minimise their maximum loss.

What should happen when draws can happen? Should we class the draw as a win because we aren't losing? Or should be class it as a loss because we are trying to win the game and a draw isn't a win? Or should we just class a draw as its own end point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Minimax strategies apply to games with *scores*. A minimax strategy maximized the guaranteed score. Assuming that you prefer a win to a draw and a draw to a loss, you can choose three scores $a > b > c$ arbitrarily and assign them as your value in the case of a win, a draw, and a loss, respectively.